# How to fix HTML validation errors - on AMP website

Tags: html, amp-html, w3c-validation

I have created an AMP website - https://full-moon-report.com/
It has no AMP errors but it has a lot of HTML errors when I check it in the HTML validator:

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Ffull-moon-report.com

The errors are:

//this happens with both the "amp" or the lightning symbol.

> Error: Attribute amp not allowed on element html at this point.
>
> Error: Attribute custom-element not allowed on element script at this
> point. </scri
>
> Error: Attribute amp-custom not allowed on element style at this
> point.

> Error: Attribute amp-boilerplate not allowed on element style at this
> point.

> Error: Attribute action-xhr not allowed on element form at this point.

> Error: Attribute submit-success not allowed on element div at this
> point.

> Error: Bad value for attribute role on element textarea.

> Warning: Attribute [hidden] is not serializable as XML 1.0.
>
> ↩   ↩   ↩

all of the errors are amp related.
What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to validate an AMP document as if it were HTML.

I'm not aware of any validation tool which supports AMP.

Comment: Oh... I thought AMP is html... so in this case.. will it be penalised by google because of invalid HTML or not? It should not...

Comment: It's bastardised HTML. I have no idea how Google's search algorithms work. They are secret.